# How to hide multiple drop downs when page loads using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I do not have direct access to the HTML file, so I've added a class to the dropdowns, however when the donation form loads all the drop downs are still visible. It's only after a I make a selection different from the default value do the drop downs disappear.

Is there a way that I can make it so only the "Select Province" drop down is visible and then the others appear as the options are selected? my code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-field-container form-row ">
    <div class="form-content">
        <span class="field-required"></span>
        <div class="form-input-label-block">
            <label for="select_province_dropdown">Select Province</label>
        </div>
        <div class="styled-select" style="width: 159px;">
            <select name="select_province_dropdown" id="select_province_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 183px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="----Select Province----">----Select Province----</option>
                <option value="AB">AB</option>
                <option value="BC">BC</option>
                <option value="MB">MB</option>
                <option value="NB">NB</option>
                <option value="NL">NL</option>
                <option value="NS">NS</option>
                <option value="ON">ON</option>
                <option value="PE">PE</option>
                <option value="QC">QC</option>
                <option value="SK">SK</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var comp = new ObservableComponent('select_province_dropdown', '');
        comp.hide = function(_hidden) {
            var _display = _hidden ? 'none' : '';
            set_display('select_province_dropdown_Row', _display);
            this.disable_submit_flag(_hidden);
        }
        //-->
        </script>
        <noscript>&lt;br/&gt;Required</noscript>
        <input type="hidden" name="select_provincesubmit" id="select_provincesubmit" value="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="custom-field-container form-row ">
    <div class="form-content hideAB">
        <span class="field-required"></span>
        <div class="form-input-label-block">
            <label for="golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown">Select Location</label>
        </div>
        <div class="styled-select" style="width: 165px;">
            <select name="golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown" id="golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 189px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="----Select Location----">----Select Location----</option>
                <option value="Lakewood Golf Resort">Lakewood Golf Resort</option>
                <option value="Twin Willows Golf Club">Twin Willows Golf Club</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var comp = new ObservableComponent('golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown', '');
        comp.hide = function(_hidden) {
            var _display = _hidden ? 'none' : '';
            set_display('golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown_Row', _display);
            this.disable_submit_flag(_hidden);
        }
        //-->
        </script>
        <noscript>&lt;br/&gt;Required</noscript>
        <input type="hidden" name="golf_for_the_cure_absubmit" id="golf_for_the_cure_absubmit" value="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.hideAB,
.hideBC,
.hideMB,
.hideNB,
.hideNL,
.hideNS,
.hideON,
.hidePE,
.hideQC,
.hideSK {display: none;}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideAB');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_bc_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideBC');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_mb_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideMB');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_nb_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideNB');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_nl_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideNL');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_ns_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideNS');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_on_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideON');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_pe_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hidePE');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_qc_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideQC');
$('#golf_for_the_cure_sk_dropdown').parent('div').addClass('hideSK');

$('#select_province_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($("#select_province_dropdown").val() === "AB") {
        $(".hideAB").attr("style", "display: block;");
    } else {
        $(".hideAB").attr("style", "display: none;");
    }
});

$('#select_province_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($("#select_province_dropdown").val() === "BC") {
        $(".hideBC").attr("style", "display: block;");
    } else {
        $(".hideBC").attr("style", "display: none;");
    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you for your time!

Edit: I'm adding the link to the donation form:  [Donation Form](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/Donation2?df_id=31358&mfc_pref=T&31358.donation=form1)

It's possible I might not be showing you something you may need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove all the css etc and use something like this

```
$(".styled-select").hide();
$("#select_province_dropdown").parent("div").show();
$("#select_province_dropdown").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() !== $("select_province_dropdown option:first").val()){
      $("#golf_for_the_cure_ab_dropdown").parent("div").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your help unfortunately when I add this to the start of the script it doesn't seem to change anything. I've removed all the css and additional code and left what you've provided but for some reason the donation form remains unchanged. I've added the link to the donation form incase I may have missed something I should have included in my original post

Comment: how are you loading script if you dont have access to html?

Comment: I have a reusable component that lets me inject into an HTML Caption field in the CMS which is how the company recommends we add our additional codes for specific pages. We have a page wrapper as well that we use to affect pages globally that are using the same wrapper.

Comment: the current code I'm using kind of works its just when the page loads all the drop downs are visible. By looking at your code I don't see why it wouldn't work so I must be doing something wrong when I'm adding it.

Comment: can you set it up in jsfiddle.net?  btw cms code might be overriding your efforts

Comment: also can you inspect one of the elements you want to hide and post screenshot of its properties

Comment: Hi Brian, you are correct I believe there's something in my CMS that's interfering with it. I tried your code in the fiddle and it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ddcjg8pz/

Comment: Woo! I figured it out. Your method works great with a bit of tweaking, I had to add some CSS to it because the CMS was overriding it because after displaying it , it would show up blank because the width was set to 0. Thanks Brian, saved me a lot of headache!